# pexpect : Is there any way to prevent input overrun while using pexpect?

Tags: python, linux, expect, tty, pexpect

Using pexpect, I am connecting to a linux machine console which is a machine with limited capabilities.
When I spawn a connection and try to execute command using send or sendline I get error saying `"ttyAMA0: 1 input overrun(s)"`

This is probably happening because `pexpect` sending input to console very fast before it is consumed and leading to input buffer overrun. 
If in some way `pexpect` slows down the speed of input to console, then it will prevent from input buffer overrun.  Is there any parameter which defines character rate for input to console?

For similar problem, tcl-expect has command send_slow which slows down input rate to provided value. Would be happy to have any equivalent to `send_slow` in python-expect.

Also tried setting window size in expect and still there's no change in the error.
Also the error I'm getting is intermittent.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This is a workaround than actual solution to buffer overrun problem. 
Did following steps:

1. Before calling python script having pexpect, set baud rate to match with the console/telnet connect using stty. E.g. `stty speed 50`
2. Spawn new shell in pexpect and set `delaybeforesend` and `delayaftersend` to desired value (only required when your devide is being too slow)
3. Replace sendline with our own custom sendline_slow which will send 1 character at a time.

def sendline_slow(spawn_id, cmd):

```
   for char  in str(cmd):
      spawn_id.send(char)
   spawn_id.send('\n')
```

Bingo. Now I am able to send commands in super slow fashion to console...!